# Make x-axis be set to 100 instead of 0 in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a bar highchart and it looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do now is this: the x-axis should start from 0, but from 100, because everything below 100 is basically a failure and everything above 100 is a success. Now, the x-axis starts from 0 and the bars go above it. If it starts from 100, the values lower than 100 should start from the x-axis and go below it. Something like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-negative), only instead of 0, the x-axis will be 100.

Comment: I assume you mean the y axis?  You can set the **threshold** property to 100 to achieve the desired result: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.threshold

Comment: jlbriggs comment should be an accepted answer, if the questions is understood correctly. @petko_stankoski - Please provide more info if the problem is not resolved.